# REST API get featured image source for custom post type

Tags: rest-api, api, json

I created a custom post type and am getting the posts using the REST API. The returned json looks like this...

```
categories: [] 
content: {raw: "Morbi mollis tellus ac sapien. Etiam ut purus matt…allis tellus, vitae iaculis lacus elit id tortor.", 
rendered: "<p>Morbi mollis tellus ac sapien. Etiam ut purus m… tellus, vitae iaculis lacus elit id tortor.</p>", 
protected: false, block_version: 0 } 
date: "2018-12-20T17:57:44" 
date_gmt: "2018-12-20T17:57:44" 
featured_media: 189 
generated_slug: "book-post-two"
...
```

Unlike normal posts, it is not returning `featured_image_src`. Just `featured_media`. Is it possible to make the features image source appear in json? How can I get it in js?

Comment: But it does, `featured_media` is the attachment ID of the featured image. Use the media endpoint to then fetch information about that attachment via fetch( '/wp-json/wp/v2/media/189)....`

Comment: You can use the global [`_embed`](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/linking-and-embedding/#embedding) parameter to include the media data in the same API response. And the data is available under the `wp:featuredmedia` item in the `_embedded` item of the main response data -  [Single post](https://demo.wp-api.org/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/35?_embed); [Multiple posts](https://demo.wp-api.org/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed&per_page=3). *For CPTs, replace the `posts` in the URL with the proper [`rest_base`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/).*